# ZF Set Theory - If $|A|^{|B|} = |B|$, then $|A| = 1 = |B|.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show (within ZF Set Theory without choice) that for any sets $A,B,C:$

If $|A|^{|B|} = |B|$, then $|A| = 1 = |B|.$

That is, if there is a bijection from $|A|^{|B|}$ to $|B|$, then  $|A| = 1 = |B|.$

Please help me..

Comment: Please show us what you tried. Also, what is $C$?

Comment: What does $|A|^{|B|}$ *mean*.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\lvert A \rvert = 1$. Then $1^{\lvert B \rvert}=1$ (there is one function from $B$ to a one-element set), so we must have $\lvert B \rvert = 1$.

Now suppose $\lvert A \rvert \geq 2$. Then $\lvert A \rvert^{\lvert B \rvert} \geq 2^{\lvert B \rvert}$, and $2^{\lvert B \rvert}>\lvert B \rvert$ by Cantor's theorem.

Comment: I don't think that $B$ is assumed to be finite. (The argument stays the same, of course).

Comment: @martin.koeberl Ah, good point. I've edited.

Comment: +1 from me then. No idea who downvoted your perfectly fine answer to a not so great question.

Comment: @martin.koeberl: I only now see this thread, so I didn't downvote this answer. But I guess some people are upset about the OP's behavior (what with the multiple accounts and bad questions), and the downvote was in a way directed to discourage people from posting answers to this user's questions.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I understand that people are annoyed by these questions, and think, these questions should be downvoted (and maybe closed). I also think that these questions should be answered. However I don't think that downvoting correct answers (if they arise) is an appropriate way to deal with this behavior though (the answer is still useful, even though it shouldn't be there in the first place).

Comment: @martin.koeberl: There's no problem with answering bad questions. But there are types of behavior that are destructive to a site like this (e.g. the behavior exhibited by the OP). If there are incentives for the OP to continue and behaving the way they do (i.e., people actually answer the questions), then there is no incentive to stop behaving like that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sure, but I'm not sure whether OP cares if the answer gets downvoted (or whether OP cares whether the question gets downvoted either). Of course, if people just stop answering these questions, this might solve the problem (or not, who knows whether OP cares about getting answers at all), and downvoting these answers might lead to this. But at least commenting why the downvote (especially here, where the answer is fine) is something one could expect. I think this kind of downvoting is also not really productive.

Comment: @martin.koeberl: Not entirely correct. Downvoting the answer might give the answerer an incentive to delete it, and downvoting the question will cause it to be removed by the automatic deletion. In addition, it will contribute to the "low quality content" score of the account. And therefore at some point the account will be banned from posting new content. Sure, this will lead to more accounts. But the system has ways to notice that there is source for all this crap. In any case, it is important to downvote, close, and delete bad content like these questions.

Comment: @martin.koeberl: To sum up this conversation, there is a lot more to voting than just saying "this specific content is good/bad", both from the socioanthropological perception of us, the users, and the code of the system. This is especially true on very large websites, such as this one.

Comment: @AsafKaragila But you still don't know what OP's point is. It should already be obvious that they don't mind opening lots of new accounts, so having old ones closed might also not be a problem for them. And as I said, I'm all in for not answering these questions, and I think one shouldn't do it, but letting people know this policy in another way than just by downvoting their answer would be a (faster) solution to this, in my opinion. And downvoting the question is an obvious thing to do in any case.

Comment: @martin: It is true that a persistent user can probably overcome all the obstacles put by the system. But they will get more stringent. And yes, I agree that posting comments to explain the situation is better. I think that this point, Chappers should be familiar with the situation. :P