# If the number of functions from $A \to B$ is equal to $A$, then the cardinality of A and B is $1$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> If the number of functions from $A \to B$ is equal to $A$, then the cardinality of A and B is $1$.

In set theory notation: If $|B|^{|A|}=|A|$ then $|A|=|B|=1$.

Any ideas? I was think of assuming $|A|$ or $|B| \neq 1$ but can't think of anything I can do after/

Comment: Is this for finite sets only, or any sets?

Comment: Any sets, I think the finite case would be easy.

Comment: Cantor's diagonal.

Comment: Your question has an answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2226353/zf-set-theory-if-ab-b-then-a-1-b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  If $|B| \gt 1, |B| \ge 2, |B|^{|A|} \ge 2^{|A|} \gt |A|$ by Cantor's theorem.  Now do the other cases.